# Consistency of GTK2 toolbars with GTK3

Tags: themes, gtk

One of the reasons why I don't like Ubuntu's default theme **Ambiance** is the unacceptable **inconsistency between GTK2 and GTK3 toolbars** as seen in **LibreOffice** and **Chromium/Chrome** web browser.

This is not the case in the **Greybird** theme, for example, which proves that it is possible.

I would appreciate if someone can help tweak this.

*Note: a similar problem with menus (inc. ComboBox menus) has been addressed here: [Consistency of GTK2 menus with GTK3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395052/consistency-of-gtk2-menus-with-gtk3)*

The two screenshots below show how **Greybird** and **Ambiance** themes display applications like (from top to bottom) **Chrome**, **LibreOffice** and **KKEdit** (with an "***undefined***" **toolbar bgcolor** which is inappropriate with the icon theme to be used in the case of **Ambiance** as opposed to consistent looks of **Greybird** or **Faience** ), unlike other apps like **Nautilus** and **gedit**, which I added at the bottom of the **Ambiance** screenshot.

Greybird theme:
[image]

Ambiance theme:
[image]

Comment: To solve this inconsistency there are two approaches: (1) using dark color only for the title, menu, and indicator bars – somehow like what Numix does; (2) using dark colors for every toolbar, which is possible with a same color for both `bg_color` and `dark_bg_color`, then you need light icons on all apps – somehow impossible with GTK-2 apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that inserting the following lines with appropriate "color codes" (e.g. ***@dark_bg_color*** , ***#808080***, etc.) in the section ***style "toolbar"*** might be a solution, although this might lead to labels etc. in some gtk2 apps unreadable (perhaps a solution might also be found for this?)

```
bg[PRELIGHT]    = <DarkColorVariantHere>
bg[NORMAL]      = <DarkColorHere>
fg[NORMAL]      = <LightColorHere>
fg[SELECTED]    = <LightColorVariantHere>
fg[INSENSITIVE] = shade(0.5, <DarkColorVariantHere>)
```